# What will happen with my DNS registrations if I change hosting plan in Azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

We're thinking of changing our web hosting plan mode from Shared to Standard but are not sure what will happen with the dns registrations I've set up for my sites. Would a move result in a new ip-adress forcing me into changing all my dns-registrations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a custom domain (e.g. www.yourdomain.com) and pointing that via a cname to the actual Azure url (e.g. yourproject.azurewebsites.net) then you shouldn't need to change your dns.  If you are pointing to an IP then you may have to change your dns.

Really depends on how you have setup your dns currently, could you elaborate on the records you have?

There is a good article on the Azure help area discussing this very topic:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Check out the 'CNAME or Alias record' section in particular.

Answer (score 3):

Use CNAME records instead.  That way you don't have to worry about it.